# Self contained component data model vs master root data model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I looking for feedback regarding how I am implementing Vue components.

I have a Vue instance that contains a list of orders and a reference to the current order. Let’s call this root instance "orders".

When the current order is set (based on clicking on one of the orders in the list), I create a new component inside "orders" called "current-order". "current-order" has a property that the parent passes it called "order_id", this property is used within "current-order" to recall the data for the order and present an editable form.

Within "current-order", besides the meta-data associated with the order (customer, etc), I have a third component to contain a group of items, let’s call this final instance "item-group".

Here is the general layout of how these instances would look:

```
orders
  current-order
    item-group
    item-group
    item-group
```

"orders" only saves a list of the orders; it does not save any order data.
"current-order" saves the meta-data associated with the order, as well as the item data.

Discussing this model with a co-worker, he explained to me that this is not the best-practice way to implement this. He felt that the proper way to implement this would be to save all of the data for all of the components on the root instance "orders", versus the way I implemented it - data saved at each level.

The model he explained seems less maintainable to me. "current-order" may be used on other pages of our application, so if I maintained its data in the root instance, I would have to do that in all of the root instances that I attach it to.

With the way I have implemented it, all you have to pass the component is an order_id, and it will fill itself with data.

He continued to explain to me that saving data on the component like I am doing can be reset by re-renders of the instance, which I didn't quite understand.

Both the way I implemented, and the way he described would work, but I'm trying to find out what the best-practice approach would be for maintainability.

Note: This is not a large SPA, and I don’t think Vuex would suite what we are trying to achieve right now.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your `child-components` are responsible for. If a `child` is extending the functionality of your `parent` component then the state should always be maintained in your parent component. For example in a `CRUD` based situation instead of creating separate components for `create` and `update` you can write only one and maintain its state (updated/created) in your parent component.

If in your `current-order` you are not updating anything related to the order then no need to maintain its state in your `order` i.e. if meta-data can be treated as a separate entity of your `order` no need to maintain it in the `parent`. But in case both order and its meta is one single entity, you should maintain its state in your parent.